# How can I control a point light's color in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have managed to have a material applied to a mesh change color (picked from an array of colors) continuously over time and I would like to do the same for a point light. How can I achieve that?

[image: Colors]

Here's the script that controls the material's color and I would like to adapt so it also controls the light's color.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ChangeColors : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Color[] colors;

    public int currentIndex = 0;
    private int nextIndex;

    public float changeColourTime = 2.0f;

    private float lastChange = 0.0f;
    private float timer = 0.0f;

    void Start()
    {
        if (colors == null || colors.Length < 2)
            Debug.Log("Need to setup colors array in inspector");

        nextIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % colors.Length;
    }

    void Update()
    {

        timer += Time.deltaTime;

        if (timer > changeColourTime)
        {
            currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % colors.Length;
            nextIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % colors.Length;
            timer = 0.0f;

        }
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.Lerp(colors[currentIndex], colors[nextIndex], timer / changeColourTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to get a reference to your point light in the script and change its color like you're doing for the renderer's material.

Your script could be improved a lot but with minimal changes it would be as follows:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ChangeColors : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Color[] colors;
    public Light pLight;

    public int currentIndex = 0;
    private int nextIndex;

    public float changeColourTime = 2.0f;

    private float lastChange = 0.0f;
    private float timer = 0.0f;

    void Start()
    {
        if (colors == null || colors.Length < 2)
            Debug.Log("Need to setup colors array in inspector");

        nextIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % colors.Length;
    }

    void Update()
    {

        timer += Time.deltaTime;

        if (timer > changeColourTime)
        {
            currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % colors.Length;
            nextIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % colors.Length;
            timer = 0.0f;

        }
        Color c = Color.Lerp(colors[currentIndex], colors[nextIndex], timer / changeColourTime);
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = c; // MIND! you should store the Renderer reference in a variable rather than getting it once per frame!!!
        pLight.color = c;
    }
}
```

[image: Unity change point light colour]

Comment: Exception : MissingComponentException: There is no 'Renderer' attached to the "Light" game object, but a script is trying to access it. on line : GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = c;

Comment: You probably attached the script to the wrong object. The way you scripted this imposes you to attach it to an object that has a renderer, for example a Cube or a Sphere. Look at hierarchy and inspector in the attached screenshot

Answer (score 0):

this is old but you just need to access the light component

`GetComponent Light.color` instead of `Renderer.material.color`

Comment: @atline Hey thank you for the edit I am new here just signed up yesterday-- perhaps you could make this better it is actually GetComponent"GreaterThanSign"Light"LessThanSign"().color but when I tried to type that last night it deleted the signs and everything in between them